# How to add a remote Postgresql db(linked server) to a Postgresql db?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a postgresql db at home and one on the cloud. I'd like to add my home db to the cloud db so I can query easily between databases. How can this be done? Without using `dblink` http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html

My home db will use a dynamic ip provider (can I add a dynamic ip address such as myhomedb.dedyn.io to postgresql settings?)

I'm stating all this in case there are any issues. My home db will only be used to update massive amount of data but isn't mission critical (as we know cloud computing isn't cheap).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `postgres-fdw` is the way to go: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html

> First install the extension:
>
> ```
> CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
> ```
>
> Then create a foreign server using `CREATE SERVER`. In this example we
>   wish to connect to a PostgreSQL server on host `192.83.123.89`
>   listening on port `5432`. The database to which the connection is made
>   is named `foreign_db` on the remote server:
>
> ```
> CREATE SERVER foreign_server
>         FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
>         OPTIONS (host '192.83.123.89', port '5432', dbname 'foreign_db');
> ```
>
> A user mapping, defined with `CREATE USER MAPPING`, is needed as well
>   to identify the role that will be used on the remote server:
>
> ```
> CREATE USER MAPPING FOR local_user
>         SERVER foreign_server
>         OPTIONS (user 'foreign_user', password 'password');
> ```
>
> Now it is possible to create a foreign table with `CREATE FOREIGN
>   TABLE`. In this example we wish to access the table named
>   `some_schema.some_table` on the remote server. The local name for it
>   will be `foreign_table`:
>
> ```
> CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_table (
>         id integer NOT NULL,
>         data text
> )
>         SERVER foreign_server
>         OPTIONS (schema_name 'some_schema', table_name 'some_table');
> ```
>
> It's essential that the data types and other properties of the columns
>   declared in `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE` match the actual remote table.
>   Column names must match as well, unless you attach `column_name` options
>   to the individual columns to show how they are named in the remote
>   table. In many cases, use of `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA` is preferable to
>   constructing foreign table definitions manually.